# Kinematics: Minimum length of horizontal path to fall back onto initial position after traversing half circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, energy-conservation, rotational-kinematics

Our professor asked us today what the minimum length of a horizontal line would have to be such that if an object moved on it with a constant initial velocity, went into a half-circle loop and fell at the top of the circle, it would fall back to its initial position.

I have been thinking about it and here’s how I’d do it:
I’d first calculate the speed the object has at the top of the circle (h=2R) by bringing it in connection with initial velocity through energy conservation.
Then I would plug that velocity into the parabolic trajectory, where I assume that the velocity is tangential and hence only has a horizontal component, set that function to 0 and find the appropriate x.

In class the professor said the answer was entirely different. I don’t care so much about calculating it correctly right now, but rather where my intuition goes wrong?

Comment: Please, explicitly tell given data: is the radius of the loop known? The answer should be found as follows: find the minimum initial velocity so that the object reaches the highest point of the loop with the minimum possible velocity, but still touching the loop itself. Then use parabolic trajectory

Comment: No, nothing is given, he was just talking generally.

Comment: Read the hint above. In few minutes, I could try to provide an answer, if the hint is not enough

Comment: But I did just that, calculated the velocity as it loses contact to the loop and then plugged that into parabolic trajectory, and he told me after class that it wasn’t the right approach

Comment: What exactly is the question being asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be split in three parts, two needed, the latter only if you want to know the initial velocity:

1. find the minimum tangential velocity to have contact at the highest point of the loop:

   $m \dfrac{v_{top}^2}{R} = m g$$\quad \rightarrow \quad $$v_{top} = \sqrt{g R}$
2. use this velocity as the velocity at the vertex of a parabolic motion described by the equations
   $m \ddot x = 0$$\quad\rightarrow\quad$$x(t) = v_{top} t$
   $m \ddot y = -m g$$\quad\rightarrow\quad$$y(t) = 2R - \dfrac{1}{2} g t^2$

   When the object touches the ground, $y(t_{g}) = 0$, so that $t_g = 2 \sqrt{R/g}$, and

   $x_g = v_{top} t_g = 2 R$
3. relate $v_{top}$ with the velocity on the horizontal path at the lowest level, before running on the loop, with mechanical energy conservation:

   $\dfrac{1}{2} m v^2_0 = \dfrac{1}{2} m v_{top}^2 + m g (2R)$
   $\quad \rightarrow \quad$$v_0 = \sqrt{v_{top}^2 + 4 gR} = \sqrt{5 g R}$

Comment: Thank you so much but I did propose exactly these steps, and I suppose the professor was wrong then in saying this is incorrectly solved

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks a right approach (one of the possible approaches) to the problem, with a right procedure. Let's wait if someone else finds a mistake in it